# checking an empty XML, XMLList or XMLListCollection in flex4

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

how do i check if an XML,XMLListCollection or XMLList has no element or contains atleast one or more elements in flex4?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#contains%28%29) method ?

sample from docs:

```
var xml:XML = 
        <order>
            <item>Rice</item>
            <item>Kung Pao Shrimp</item>
        </order>;
trace(xml.item[0].contains(<item>Rice</item>)); // true
trace(xml.item[1].contains(<item>Kung Pao Shrimp</item>)); // true
trace(xml.item[1].contains(<item>MSG</item>)); // false
```

Comment: Hi @George Profenza,that would be fine if you atleast know that the xml contains some elements called <item>..in my case, i am not interested in what it contains..i just want to see if the xml has some elements in it. i couldn't use the .simple() and .complex() since the elment can have atleast one element..but the problem with testing it with those is that..if it is an XML with a complex structure then the condition becomes false and thatz not my goal..i just need to know if it has an element..dont care if it is one or more..